# Filter collection by associated model field in Rails

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models as follows:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
end
```

And I have a collection like:

```
@books = Book.where(something: "...")
```

I would like to filter this collection with unique authors. Not select unique authors from collection. Just collection of books with unique value of author_id column.

**upd:**
 For example I have collection

```
> #<ActiveRecord::Relation 
[#<Book id: 1, title: "Tails", author_id: 1>,
<Book id: 2, title: "Tails part 2", author_id: 1>,
<Book id: 3, title: "Tails part 3", author_id: 1>,
<Book id: 4, title: "Stories part 1", author_id: 5>,
<Book id: 5, title: "Stories part 2", author_id: 5>]>
```

It should be like this:

```
> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
<Book id: 1, title: "Tails", author_id: 1>,
<Book id: 4, title: "Stories part 1", author_id: 5>
]>
```

Comment: So you want a single, arbitrary book listed for each author?

Comment: Yes. I think this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward way of accomplishing this is to first find the author ids you want to filter by.

`author_ids = Author.where(first_name: 'Deborah').pluck(:id)`

Let's say `author_ids` now contains the array `[1, 2, 3]`. Now you can use this array of author ids to find books with these authors.

`Book.where(author_id: author_ids)`

This can be read as, "Find books where the author_id is in this list of ids." The resulting SQL would be:

`SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."author_id" IN (1, 2, 3)`

**EDIT:**

After clarification from the question author, I believe this is what is needed:

`Book.select('DISTINCT ON (author_id) *')`

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. But this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Maybe I wasn't so clear in my question. See update.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.